# how to fix: System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException for arraylist

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-7.5

I'm writing a new DataContract to our service (which is in windows service and exposed by iis). in the main class i have an Arraylist member that when i expose i get System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException if i change the member to "List<>" then all is great (and it goes through from postman->iis->windows service).

the class is:

```
namespace Kitchen
{
    [Serializable()]
    [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(Fruit))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(Fruit))]
    public class Foods
    {

        private ArrayList uniFood;
        private List<string> lstCity;

        [DataMember]
        [XmlElement(typeof(Fruit))]         
        public ArrayList FoodArr
        {
            get
            {
                return uniFood;
            }
            set
            {
                uniFood = value;
            }
        }

        [DataMember]
        [XmlIgnore]
        public List<string> CityGrown
        {
            get
            {
                return lstCity;
            }
            set
            {
                lstCity = value;
            }
        }


        [DataMember]
        [XmlIgnore]
        public bool IsMerge
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [DataMember]
        [XmlIgnore]
        public bool IsRipe
        {
            get;
            set;
        }


        public Foods()
        {
            uniFood = new ArrayList();
            lstCity = new List<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

the error i get when trying to send class to service reference:
System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' is a recursive collection data contract which is not supported. Consider modifying the definition of collection 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' to remove references to itself.

any help would be appreciated

This is a new feature in api, working on vs2013. in the past i've tried changing the arraylist to List<> and that helps but i need it as array list because when serializing to xml  it comes out as:

Comment: just me being pedantic, but shouldn't  public Rules() be public Foods() ?

Comment: Is there a chance you see what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please use [CollectionDataContract(...)] attribute instead of [DataContract] attribute when Data Contract class has an collection member, please refer to the below document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/collection-types-in-data-contracts
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.collectiondatacontractattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8